# onRestoreInstanceState Not Reloading All Views

Tags: android, onrestoreinstancestate

I'm developing an application where users fill out a form with photos and a few yes/no questions. When yes is selected you need to add extra information in a dialogue. Then this information is inserted into a `TextView` and this `TextView` inserted into a `LinearLayout`.

The problem is, when the user switches to another application this screen goes to background and is later destroyed by Android (because the system needs memory). Then when the user returns to the application, the `onRestoreInstanceState()` method is called, bringing back some variables but not the `TextView` inside `LinearLayout`. I am using Android annotations to return these variables. How do I restore those Android views?

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/estoque_zerado_pergunta_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/existe_estoque_zerado"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_large_material"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_estoque_zerado_sim"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/sim" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_estoque_zerado_nao"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:text="@string/nao"/>

                </RadioGroup>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/estoque_zerado_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/estoque_zerado_itens_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <!--Lista de itens aqui-->

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/add_estoque_zerado_item"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_adicionar"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/adicionar_estoque_zerado"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/adicionar_estoque_zerado"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("onRestoreInstanceState", "onRestoreInstanceState: chamou onRestoreInstanceState");}

    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    Log.d("onSaveInstanceState", "onSaveInstanceState: chamou onSaveInstanceState");}
```

Sorry for my beginner English.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have  `android:visibility="gone"`  on your layout is that normal?

Comment: It is a prerequisite. Each question should appear only after the previous be answered.

Comment: can you make sure your linearLayout is not restored?(by using [Hierarchy View](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer.html) for exemple)

Comment: I'm tring to do it, but Hierarchy View is not working on my moto e device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i know `onRestoreInstanceState` does not restore your views. `onCreate` and `onRestoreInstanceState` uses same `Bundle` so initialize your views and check `savedInstanceState` in `onCreate`. Check docs out below.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#RestoreState

Comment: "The default implementation of this method performs a restore of any view state that had previously been frozen by onSaveInstanceState(Bundle).". This is by the first link you gave me, abou onRestoreInstanceState.

And from same page: "The default implementation takes care of most of the UI per-instance state for you by calling onSaveInstanceState() on each view in the hierarchy that has an id, and by saving the id of the currently focused view (all of which is restored by the default implementation of onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle))." This is about onSaveInstanceState.

Comment: The point is, some view's are restored, only the textview's inside linearlayout are not restored.

Comment: After testing some situations i changed the code in onRestoreInstanceState to onCreate then the textview`s are restored now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

You have to save variable you want to get back.
in onSaveInstanceState you save your data

```
static final String SAVE_STRING = "string_to_save";
...
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save variable value on bundle
    savedInstanceState.putInt(SAVE_STRING, yourstring);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

then you can retrieve them in onRestoreInstanceState

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Restore state members from saved instance
    yourstring = savedInstanceState.getInt(SAVE_STRING);
}
```

Comment: I save all variables that i needed, the problem is the textview's inside of linearlayout.

Comment: you have android:visibility="gone" on your second LinearLayout is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

Your views need to have an ID if you want Android to automatically save the state in onSaveInstanceState